# PHP fwrite() performance and memory issues

Tags: php, performance, memory, fastcgi

***Edit***: Originally I thought this issue was related to PHP-FPM because my host implied so (read below). I got around to configuring my test server to use PHP-FPM (cgi-fcgi) and the script ran without performance / memory issues. There is probably something else on my host's server that is doing weird stuff like tracking file writes and putting written content into memory for no reason. Does anyone know if there is such software / modules that could do this? I shall contact my host again in the meantime...

**The problem**

I have a PHP script that writes data to file using `fwrite()`. On my shared hosting, which runs CloudLinux server, performance is slow and memory gets exhausted when a lot of data needs to be written. It seems the problem is with PHP-FPM that Apache uses on the server. If I SSH into the server and run the same script with PHP-CLI, performance is much better (up to 7 times faster) and memory usage stays more or less the same throughout the duration of the script.

I wrote a simple test script to illustrate this:

```
echo 'SAPI: ' . php_sapi_name(); // Shows if you're using fcgi or cli
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') { // Set appropriate line break char
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    $eol = '<br>';
}
echo $eol;
echo 'Starting fwrite...' . $eol;

$time_start = microtime(true); 
$fh = fopen('/some/path/test-fw.txt', 'w');
$i = 0;
while ($i < 2000000) {
    $str = 'row-' . $i . ': this is a test string abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg abcdefg ';
    fwrite($fh, $str);
    $i++;
}
echo 'fwrite done!' . $eol;
echo 'Time taken: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start) . 's' . $eol;
fclose($fh);
echo 'Sleeping for 60s before exiting...';
sleep(60); // Give you some time to check memory usage (in CPanel)
```

Test results:

- When called from browser, memory usage starts at around 30MB and climbs up to ~330MB by the end of the script. Execution time is around 78 seconds.
- When called with PHP-CLI, memory usage stays at around 30MB. Execution time is around 10 seconds.

Memory usage is the Physical Memory Usage shown in CPanel. Incidentally, the file size is around 300MB, so I was thinking if the contents written with fwrite() were also put into memory by PHP-FPM!

I hoped to get around this problem by doing an `exec('php-cli script.php')` in another script but this didn't work. All it did was create a `php-cli` process *as a child* of the `php-cgi` process.

I was told by my host's support staff that  "CGI puts everything into memory unless you tell it to 'dump' it, and CGI is designed to be less CPU intensive". I was somewhat baffled because I couldn't see what's there to "dump" in my code to free up memory. I mean, in my test script, does CGI store each `$str` passed to `fwrite()` unless I explicitly disallow it? If so, how do I do that (tried `unset()` which didn't help)?

Unfortunately, I could not change PHP handler on shared hosting. Otherwise, I would have just used mod_php which I am currently using on my local test server without the stated problems.

I wonder if anyone has similar experience who could point me in the right direction. If it is of any use, I am with Inmotion Hosting's Power plan that has 2GB physical memory allocated to my account.

***To clarify:*** memory seems to drop back to normal shortly after `fclose()` is called and the sleep period starts. So I do think it's `fwrite()` that's causing this wierd issue. `fflush()` and `set_file_buffer($fh, 0)` didn't help. It's as though content is being written to disk but also kept in memory at the same time, and I don't know what's causing the latter...

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure, but would [fflush()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) not forcibly flush your fwrite() output to the file instead of leaving it all in memory? I would not flush all the time, but for instance every `$i % 1000 == 0`.

Comment: I think the support staff is talking about the output buffer that goes to the client, not things like `fwrite()`. There are probably other settings in `php.ini` that affect how `fwrite()` works.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like the file writes might be buffered in memory. I'm not running PHP-FPM so I can't test it myself, but what happens if you call `set_file_buffer($fh, 0);` before the writes?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, `fflush()`  and `set_file_buffer()` doesn't change anything. If there are settings in `php.ini` that affects how `fwrite()` works, what would they be? FYI I did make sure that the same `php.ini` was used when running the test script through PHP-FPM and PHP-CLI.